# How to view IOS documentation using Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Is there a shortcut i can use to display or search `Obj-C` API?

Say, i'd like to learn more about what `IBAction` does, i wonder if i can mouse over it and view documentation. Is there a way this can be enabled? A side bar possibly?

Please advise

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Option-click a class name and a window will pop up with a description.  Click the book icon and the help window will open to that class.  Command click to view the h file.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know off, but you may see the source code at any time, and that has plenty of documentation on the comments.

Answer (score 1):

1. Within the Quick Help information, click **Open in Developer Documentation** to access Xcode documentation, which includes more thorough explanations and references to related functions.
2. You can also access **Developer Documentation** window from the Xcode **Help** menu.
3. Another option is by using the keyboard shortcut **Command+Shift+0**.

Answer (score 1):

Command + click on it, then click Show Quick Help
[image]

Also there's a keyboard shortcut for opening general documentation list.

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>0 (Zero)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4, the Organizer window has a documentation section which can be accessed from the Right sidebar (Quick Help, which is part of the button group to enable the bottom bar (GDB by default) as well as the left sidebar (Class tree/etc) ) of the main Xcode window whenever you click on basically anything in the code (if its a custom method/variable it only tells you where it is defined). However, if it is something like IBAction it will pop up a brief definition as well as a link to open the previously mentioned organizer to the appropriate documentation page.